Azure Linux Web App host disk space more than 90%
There is an Azure Web App on Linux that uses a container. It has 90% Host Disk Space. And there is no way to clean up images like docker image prune. The container itself has 2.5gb of host disk space. I've tried downgrading and upgrading the plan, didn't help.

I downgraded and upgrade the service plan, which freed up 2GB.
Cleared all logs in the container.
Insights logs are disabled.
File logs are enabled with a 35MB limit and 1-day retention.
Cleared manifests in ACR.
Restarted the Web App.
Reduced the image size from 3GB to 1.5GB.

After all these actions, the result is:
Filesystem                                                                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                                                                                49G   41G  5.6G  89% /
tmpfs                                                                                  64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm                                                                                    62M     0   62M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1                                                                              49G   41G  5.6G  89% /temp
/dev/sda3                                                                              63G   14G   47G  22% /appsvctmp
devtmpfs                                                                              4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev/tty
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /sys/firmware

Used du -sh /*:
(app-3.12) root@41312aw235g:/app# du -sh /*
160K    /appsvctmp
0       /bin
4.0K    /boot
0       /dev
3.0M    /etc
4.0K    /home
0       /lib
0       /lib64
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot read directory '/proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/proc/146/task/146/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/146/task/146/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/146/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/146/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       /proc
80M     /root
32K     /run
0       /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
8.0K    /tmp
306M    /app
1.2G    /usr
262M    /var

How can I clean this up? I believe the space is being taken up by image manifests, but I don't have access to clean them up.

Open the newui(https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui) from KUDU, you can delete unnecessary files from there.

but I don't have access to clean them up. What is the error you are getting ?

@Harshitha , When entering the container I have only 3gb occupied. The command du -su /* shows that overlay is >90% full, but there are no files in the container, I don't know what to clear to free up space. Is there any way to get to this HostDisk which is created for Web App?

@Harshitha I also just decided to create a new service plan, on POV3. So far I have put a stub that there is NGINX container, I go there by SSH, and in the new service plan, the new web app is busy overlaying 9G 35G 12G 75% /. What took up 35 GB? It's a brand-new web app, there's nothing there yet...

Do you have access to the container registry in the portal ?

@Harshitha, yes

Have you tried deleting the docker images from there ?

@Harshitha, I deleted the manifests, but didn't delete the images themselves

Refer this link once

@Harshitha, Sorry, but where exactly can I use docker rm? I am using a Linux Web App where I simply specify the image from ACR in the deployment.

Check if there are any unused images..

@Harshitha I'm sorry. The disk space in ACR doesn't seem to relate to the disk space in the Web App. I deleted a 4GB image from ACR, but the disk size in the Web App didn't change.

@Harshitha, I mentioned earlier that I created a new Service Plan PoV3 in the same resource group. I deployed a Linux Web App using the standard Azure image with the nginx service. When I SSH into it, 75% of the memory was already occupied.
